# Error installing Jedi VCL

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I have Delphi XE Pro, I'm trying to install the latest **Jedi Visual Component Library**.
The version is: **JVCL348CompleteJCL26-Build5178**

I followed the instructions and deleted all old versions.
Installed JCL. No problem.
When installing the JVCL using the install.bat I got a fatal error

**File not found: JvTypes.dcu**

[image: JVCL Compile Error]

I posted this problem on the [jedi.org issue tracker](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=6416), a week ago but nobody seems to be answering questions there.

I have a **JvTypes.pas** from an older version of JVCL. Can  I use that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Apparently not all the files got unzipped.

I deleted the JVCL folder and then re-unzipped it.

This time the installation was completed.